# NS2: functionality of insert-delayer

Tags: ns2

i have a program for GSM simulation in TCL script and i am not getting the meaning of below lines of code:

```
 $ns insert-delayer $nodes(ms) $nodes(bs1) [new Delayer] 

 $ns insert-delayer $nodes(bs1) $nodes(ms) [new Delayer] 

 $ns insert-delayer $nodes(ms) $nodes(bs2) [new Delayer]

 $ns insert-delayer $nodes(bs2) $nodes(ms) [new Delayer]
```

Please can anyone tell what is the functionality of delayer

Comment: 'insert-delayer' seems to appear in the ns2 code only in `tcl/lib/ns-queue.tcl` : https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7uqn7fhc54un4o/insert-delayer.txt?dl=0

Comment: Ref. `tcl/lib/ns-queue.tcl:580: $link insert-delayer $delayer` → → `delayer` is defined in ns-2.35/queue/{ delayer.h, delayer.cc } .... and described in `ns-2.35/CHANGES.html` line 736. Search command = `$ cd ns-2.35/ && grep -Rin delayer *`